# Itemtap on list not working in sencha touch2

Tags: list, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, tap

I have root view Extends `Ext.navigation.View` . I'm pushing a view called Add Item.

```
   this.push({
        title:'Add Item',
        xtype:'additempanel'
    });
```

From that view I'm again pushing a view called Select Category

```
button.up('itempanel').push({
        xtype: 'selectcategorypanel',
        title: 'Select Category'
    });
```

I have a list in this view .But tapping an item on this list is calling root view's itemtap.

My app controller

```
config: {
        refs: {
items :"itempanel",
SelectCategoryPanel : "selectcategorypanel"
}



'selectCategoryPanel list' : {
                itemtap: 'selectCategoryItemTap'
            }

  'itempanel list' : {
                itemtap: 'showPost'
            },
```

The show post method is always getting called. The item tap of selectCategoryPanel is never called please help me.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector for the `selectCategoryItemTap` listener appears to be incorrect. You can fix it by either using the `xtype` of the view, or by setting another `ref` that points to the list.

By `xtype`:

```
control: {
    'selectcategorypanel list': {
        itemtap: 'selectCategoryItemTap'
    }
}
```

By `ref`:

```
refs: {
    selectCategoryPanelList: 'selectcategorypanel list'
},
control: {
    selectCategoryPanelList: {
        itemtap: 'selectCategoryItemTap'
    }
}
```

Right now the `'selectCategoryPanel list'` selector isn't actually pointing to anything that Sencha can find, so it won't be able to attach the listener to it.

Comment: Now both are getting called. But again real dat is coming in parent. Getting null on child.          selectCategoryItemTap: function(list,index,element,record){
        console.log('Hi');
        selectedCategories.push(record);
        console.log(record);
    },

Comment: If you aren't wanting `showPost()` to be called, you'll likely need to be more specific in your selector for it if there are two separate lists.

Comment: only one list in this view. But I have another list in root view.